# CSS vertical-align property doesn't work

Tags: html, css, text-align

Hey there I have the following CSS code:

```
.parent
{
    position : 'absolute';
    top : '50px';
    left : '50px';
    width : '400px';
    height : '160px';
    padding : '10px';
    border : '2px solid';
    border-color : '#444444';
    background-color : '#FF0000';
    text-align : 'center';
    /*display : inline; tried this also and didn't work.*/
}

.child
{
    color : '#123456';
    font-size : '16px';
    font-family : 'Arial';
    vertical-align : 'middle';
}
```

I just want to put the child's content in the center (x and y) of the parent div, but it's not working, it only shows me the text in the top side of the parent element. Any suggestion? thank you.

Comment: Why are there quotes around all of the property values?

Comment: I'm sorry, I just did a quick translation from a JavaScript class I'm making and forgot to take them off.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`vertical-align` has a deceiving name. It doesn't actually vertically align elements in the way that you think it does.

If your child has only one line of text, you can use the `line-height` trick to center it:

```
.parent {
    line-height: 160px; /* Height of the parent */
}
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vVAdZ/**

Another way is to fake a table:

```
.parent {
    display: table;
}

.child {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vVAdZ/3/**

Comment: I have 3 divs inside the div parent, the div parent has it's width / height and I want to put all of them in the middle of the whole parent div.

Comment: Perfect! works fine, (it took me hours to find the solution lol) thank's to everyone..

Comment: I can't imagine the line-height is a valid solution. What about lines that wrap or a non-fixed-height parent?

Answer (score 2):

Lose the quotes in your CSS property values and add `line-height: 160px;` to .parent

Answer (score 2):

Take whatever the width is, which in this case is 400, and divide by 2 for half of the div. Then take half of the height 160, and divide by 2 for half the height, and you should get the center.